# Class 'Mpdf\Mpdf' not found (Laravel Job)

Tags: laravel, mpdf

I have the following code for a laravel Job. It works just fine when in the Controller, but once I transferred it to a job, it fails with the error

`Class 'Mpdf\Mpdf' not found`

I have imported the class at the top of the job as I did with the controller so can't figure out why it can't find it.

```
<?php

    namespace App\Jobs;

    use Mpdf\Mpdf;
    use App\DocumentRequest;
    use Illuminate\Bus\Queueable;
    use Intervention\Image\Facades\Image;
    use Illuminate\Queue\SerializesModels;
    use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Storage;
    use Illuminate\Queue\InteractsWithQueue;
    use Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\ShouldQueue;
    use Illuminate\Foundation\Bus\Dispatchable;

    class ProcessUploads implements ShouldQueue
    {

    use Dispatchable, InteractsWithQueue, Queueable, SerializesModels;

    protected $uuid;

    public function __construct($uuid)
    {
        $this->uuid = $uuid;
    }


    public function handle()
    {
        $mpdf =  new Mpdf();

        $mpdf->WriteHTML($this->uuid);

        $mpdf->Output('Output.pdf', 'F');
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you restart the queue after making changes in your job class ?

Comment: Ah damn! That was it! Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Steps to do for this type of errors:

1. Check composer that this package is already installed
2. Use the `composer dump-autoload` command to update autoload classes.
3. Check the documentation of this package for the valid class call
4. **Restart the queue** (because queue and tinker cache the code)

Comment: I tried dump autoload. It works fine in a controller just not in a job.

Comment: try to use it from inside tinker and watch what will happen

Answer (score 0):

My supervisor job was running in the background and hadn’t been restarted to reflect the changes.